# If graphs of the functions $y=ln x$ and $y=ax$ intersect at exactly 2 points then a must be?

Tags: functions

*If graphs of the functions $y=ln x$ and $y=ax$ intersect at exactly 2 points then a must be?*
Ok I know the graphs of these two functions but what should be the calculus based technique to find the solution to this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Clearly when $ a \leq 0 $ there is only one intersection, hence $ a > 0 $

Looking at a graph, as you increase $a$ from 0, there will be two intersections (one near $x = 1$, one farther away), until $ y = ax $ is tangent to $ y = \ln{x} $ (when there will naturally only be one). For greater $a$ there are no intersections.

Therefore we need to find when $ y = ax $ is tangent to $ y = \ln{x} $.

The equation of the tangent line (in point slope form) to  $ y = \ln{x} $ at $(x_0, \ln{x_0})$ is $$ y-  \ln{x_0} = \frac{1}{x_0}(x - x_0) $$

If this is to be in the form $ y = ax $ we require the constant term of the above equation to be 0. Rearranging this means that $ \ln{x_0} = 1$, hence $x_0 = e$, and the slope a = $\frac{1}{e}$.

Hence there are two intersections when $ 0 < a < \frac{1}{e} $.

Comment: Really imaginative and out of the box :-)!!Loved your solution :-)!!

Answer (score 2):

Using differentiation you can find an equation for the tangent line through $\langle x_0,\ln(x_0)\rangle$. What form does it take if you insist that $\langle0,0\rangle$ is one of its points? There you have found the line $y=ax$ having exactly one point in common with the graph of $y=\ln x$. Draw conclusions.

Answer (score 1):

Consider the function $f(x)=\ln x-ax$. We are interested in the number of zeros of $f$ (if $f(x)=0$ then $y=\ln x$ and $y=ax$ intersect for this value of $x$). We begin by looking at the derivative of $f$. $f^\prime(x) = \frac{1}{x}-a$, so $f^\prime(x)=0$ only for $x=\frac{1}{a}$. If $a\le 0$ this is outside the possible range for $x$, as we have $\ln x$ in our expression. In this case $f^\prime(x)$ has the same sign for all $x$ in the range, and a continuous function which is either always increasing or always decreasing can have at most one zero.

If on the other hand $a>0$, we see that $f^{\prime\prime}(x)=-\frac{1}{x^2}$ such that $f^{\prime\prime}\left(\frac{1}{a}\right)=-a^2<0$. This tells us that the point $x=\frac{1}{a}$ is a global maximum of $f$. At this point we also note that $f\to -\infty$ as $x\to 0$ and as $x\to \infty$, such that we have exactly two zeros if and only if $f\left(\frac{1}{a}\right)>0$ (Try to sketch this, and remember that $f$ is continuous).

So now it only remains to determine those $a>0$ such that $f\left(\frac{1}{a}\right)>0$. 
$$f\left(\frac{1}{a}\right) = \ln\frac{1}{a}-1=-\ln a - 1$$
and $\ln a < -1$ if and only if $a < e^{-1}$. So the answer is that there are exactly two intersection points for $a\in(0,e^{-1})$.

Answer (score 0):

Let $y_1 = ln x, y_2 = ax$. Looking at graphs of $y_1$ and $y_2$ for various values of $a$, you'll find either 2 intersections or none. So there has to be a particular value of $a$, where there is exactly one intersection. Let's call it $a_0$. If we find $a_0$, we can find the range of values of $m$ where there are 2 intersesections of $y_1$ and $y_2$.

We can also see that for this $a_0$, at some $x=x_0$, $y_2$ is tangent of $y_1$ ('exactly one intersection'). So, at $x_0$ for $a=a_0$, the slope of $y_1 = $ slope of $y_2$. i.e: \begin{equation} y_1'(x_0) = a_0 \end{equation} Solving, we get: \begin{equation} x_0 = 1/a_0 \end{equation}

Also, at $x=x_0$, we have one intersection. Thus $y_1(x_0) = y_2(x_0)$: \begin{equation} 1nx_0 = a_0x_0 \\ x_0 = e^{(a_0x_0)} \end{equation} From earlier, $a_0x_0$ = 1. Thus\begin{equation} x_0 = e \\ a_0 = 1/e\end{equation} Hence, at $a = 1/e$ we have 1 intersection. For $a \in (0,1/e)$ we have 2 intersections. For $a \in (1/e , \infty)$, no intersection between $y_1$ and $y_2$.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).